# remove line break only on lines containing a string / expression with command line tools

Tags: shell, replace, sed, newline, tr

I'm looking for the simplest way to replace \n characters but only on given lines containing a certain expression.

The input looks like this

```
00:03:04
text alphabetic abcde
00:03:08
text alphabetic abcde
00:03:17
text alphabetic abcde
00:03:26
text alphabetic abcde
```

The output would be like

```
00:03:04 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:08 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:17 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:26 text alphabetic abcde
```

now I'd like to replace the \n only on the non-alphabetical lines.

I guess the easiest way would be with 'tr', but I can't see how to limit that to the specified lines.

I fiddled with sed, but this seems rather problematic.

I can't believe there isn't an elegant way to say 
"replace newline on lines starting with  [0-9][0-9]:".

How would you go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with the "hold buffer":

```
~$ sed -r'/[0-9][0-9]:/ {N; s/ *\n/ /}' myfile
00:03:04 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:08 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:17 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:26 text alphabetic abcde
```

`N` says: read the next line and append to the current one.
Then we do the substitution `s/\n/ /` (because in your example you have some spaces after the time, you have to remove then too, hence the `*` part).
And that, only if the line start with  `/[0-9][0-9]:/`

Note that if your file is strictly of the form:

```
time
text
time
text
...
```

You don't need the `/[0-9]/` part:

```
~$ sed '{N; s/ *\n/ /}' myfile
00:03:04 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:08 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:17 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:26 text alphabetic abcde
```

Comment: Man, that's perfect, including your explanation! Thank you! I spent almost an hour gxxgling for that and came up only with the most mindbending sed constructions.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS' file
00:03:04 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:08 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:17 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:26 text alphabetic abcde
```

This change the Output Record Selector based on the line number (odd/even)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join each pair of lines:

```
paste -d " " - - < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^[0-9:]*$/!{H;x;s/\n/ /;p;b};h' input
```

*Gives:*

```
00:03:04 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:08 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:17 text alphabetic abcde
00:03:26 text alphabetic abcde
```